# Steepest Descent/Newton

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization

Suppose these over-determined system of equations:
$$
|\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{v_n}| = A, \qquad n = 1,2,\cdots,N-1
$$

$$
\mathbf{v_n}=
[1 \quad w^n \quad  w^{2n} \quad  \cdots \quad  w^{(N-1)n}]^T , \qquad w = e^{-j\frac{2\pi}N}
$$
where $P$ is a known support of positive-valued vector $\mathbf{x}$.

Since I failed finding analytic solution for this system of equations, I am trying to solve it using numerical optimization methods such as Gradient Descent, Newton, ... .
First of all is it a good idea to do this minimization?
$$
\min f(\mathbf{x}) = \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \left||\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{v_n}| - A\right|^2
$$
And which numerical algorithm would be better ? Also what method I should use to satisfy the constraints: $supp(\mathbf{x}) = P$ and $x_i \ge  0$ ?

Since accuracy is more important than speed for me, I think Newton would be better? and using gradient projection for constraints seems easiest one to use! What's your suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by "$P$ is a known support of positive-valued vector $x$"?  Nothing called $P$ appears in your problem.  And what is the "support" of a vector?

Comment: It means $x_i$'s are zero for $i \notin P$.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, we are given that the discrete Fourier coefficients of $x$ all have magnitude $A$.  If we didn't know anything about the support of $x$, then $x$ wouldn't be determined, because then the phases of the discrete Fourier coefficients of $x$ could be anything.  With the condition that $x_i = 0$ for all $i \notin P$, I suppose there's hope that $x$ could be uniquely determined, but it doesn't seem clear that this is the case.  It seems like we'd need to know more about $P$ to know if $x$ is uniquely determined.

Comment: support of $x$ is not related to phase of its DFT. I mean constraint of $P$ being support of $x$ doesn't make the condition better, maybe it makes it more difficult.

Comment: There's been a lot of work on recovering the phases of the discrete Fourier coefficients of a signal, given only their magnitudes.  Potentially something in that literature could be helpful.

Comment: For example the paper Compressed Sensing Phase Retrieval by Moravec, Romberg, and Baraniuk seems potentially relevant.